# How to improve the efficiency of this python function?

Tags: python, performance

I pass a list (called a) of characters. The characters could be either letters or emojis.
Ex: a=['a','b','f','a','g', '']
Then I count the occurrences of each character in the list.
This function return just the most frequent character by alphabetical order.
ex_n.2: if the most frequents characters are 'b' and 'a', it returns me 'a'

```
def occorrenze(a):

    dix={} #dictionary

    for i in a:
        if i in dix:
            dix[i]+=1
        else:
            dix[i]=1

    #it finds me the max values in the dict.
    maxvalues=max(dix.values())

    #it creates a list with the keys having the max values
    maxkeys= [k for k,v in dix.items() if v == maxvalues]

    #It return just one characters, the one first in alphabetical order
    return sorted(maxkeys)[0]
```

I don't know how to make this function faster.

Comment: The built-in `collections.Counter` class can do this for you, and can even return the top 10 values.  You just say "counts = Counter(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @TimRoberts commented, one can use `collections.Counter`. This object will count the number of times each item occurs. Then we can find the most common objects, and in the case of ties, we sort the values.

In the example below, `b` and `d` both occur three times. But using `counter.most_common(n=1)` would give us `d` because `d` came before `b` in the list of characters. Therefore, we find all values that have the max count and sort those values.

Note that `sorted` will sort upper-case before lower-case.

```py
from collections import Counter

string = ["d", "d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "a"]

counts = Counter(string)
most_common = counts.most_common()[0]  # ('d', 3)
most_common_count = most_common[1]  # 3
tied_values = [s for s, count in counts.items() if count == most_common_count]  # ['b', 'd']
tied_values = sorted(tied_values)  # ['b', 'd']
```

Comment: I can't use other libraries

Comment: This is part of the standard library. Can you not use any imports? You need to clarify that in your question.